# Create user directly in AD in specific group PowerShell

Tags: powershell

During the night I have started to coding with PowerShell.

It is necessary for my job to create the similar account but not in the same folder. I wrote this code:

```
 $name = read-host "Enter your name"
 $given = read-host "Entrer votre prenom"
 $PWD = read-host   "entrer le mot de passe "

 new-aduser -name $name -GivenName $given -surname gi010bbins -Samaccountname lo1000iu -UserPrincipalname lol1@tes000t.com -description tes000tg -office lol -Passthru |Disable-adaccount
```

The first line is perfectly fine, but the second line of code has an issue, indeed nothing happens in Active Directory. I tried several things without success.

```
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Ressource -Member Applications -name $name -GivenName $given -surname gi010bbins -Samaccountname lo1000iu -UserPrincipalname lol1@tes000t.com -description tes000tg -office lol  -Passthru |Disable-adaccount -pwd $pwd
```

[Active Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr9ib.png)

[image]

I would like to create the second account directly folder's ressource.

I hope you will help me .

Comment: I'm affraid you are missing the basics of Active Directory and in particular the difference between an Organizational Unit and a Group. You are trying to add a user in a specific OU and you are using the command to add a user to a group (in your question you are also talking about a group but your screenshot clearly shows an OU).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in the GUI anyway, there is little need to try and do this from scratch.

Just use the Windows Server ADAC and do this step manually once and let the ADAC automatically write the PoSH code for you, which you can later tweak however you choose?

> Step-By-Step: Utilizing PowerShell History Viewer in Windows Server
>   2012 R2 The Windows Server 2012 Active Directory Administrative Center
>   (ADAC) makes the process of viewing cmdlets history quite easy as it
>   can be completed via a few simple steps.  In this example Windows
>   PowerShell History Viewer will be utilized in ADAC to construct a
>   Windows PowerShell script that will add users to a group.
>
> 9.Copy the command and paste it into your desired editor to construct your script.
>
> This now allows an IT administrator to modify the command to be able
>   to add a different user to a desired group without memorizing the
>   required cmdlets. PowerShell can be a great time saver for any IT
>   professional.
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/03/04/step-by-step-utilizing-powershell-history-viewer-in-windows-server-2012-r2

Comment: omg ,thank you so much for this information .
I can improve my skill on powershell with this tool .

Yes I will tweak my script

Comment: No worries. Glad it will help. It's a very under utilized tool and vary sadly, not covered often enough as a launching pad for folks wrapping their heads / hands around this sort of thin, Especially all the AD centric stuff. There are other legacy tools that will do similar stuff, though not as dynamic / complete and ADAC.